# Import old minitab project files (MPJ) to R

Tags: r, minitab-16

I have several MPJ-files (version 16 and older) in Minitab. They cannot be read by newer versions of minitab and I need some way to retreive the data (I do not need graphs etc just the data). Is there a way to import the data from olkd MPJ files in R?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good first-stop for researching something like this; in fact, asking us to recommend a package/library is specifically off-topic, so this question might be closed as such. Have you done any research? Have you found any software that works with newer versions but not older versions? Is there a good sample of "old" minitab files that one might be able to test on? I found [this](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/20/integration/r-integration-guide/install-r-and-mtbr/) which seems like it _may_ work, there's no way to know with what you've provided here.

Comment: Well I did my search already and - as you can see from my question - I have an MPJ, so called project file, that contains both datasets, graphs and other stuff. All I need is a way to retrieve the data sheets. Foreign package can read mtp portable worksheet, which does not work. Further, as you could read yourself, the mtbr works up to R 4.1.0. Feel free to ignore any question you find annoying.